Rxjs observer un-subscription in angular
I am creating a rxjs Subject inside a angular component and creating a subscription to that Subject in that component itself like below
@Component({
    selector: 'cp-cart-control-comp',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: './cart-control.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './cart-control.component.scss',
    ]
})

export class CartControlComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges { 
     /**
     * Observable for auto search input changes
     */
    public autoSearchInputChanges = new Subject<any>();
    ngOnInit() {
        // Observable for auto search changes
        this
          .autoSearchInputChanges
          .subscribe(eventData => {
              //some logic here
          })
    }
}


In the above code, do I need to write un-subscription logic for this.autoSearchInputChanges.subscribe() observers.
When this angular component goes out of scope won't autoSearchInputChanges also goes out of scope and won't then its subscriptions be automatically garbage collected?

The second sentence of the statement is wrong. Subscriptions to infinite Observables will not be unsubscribed on destroy, unless the async pipe is used, or they are manually unsubscribed on destroy. If you are subscribing to a finite Observable, the first sentence might be correct.

Where does this statement come from? Do you have a link?

Does the duplicate answer your question?

I think the linked question answers it - this is a subscription to an infinite Observable which will produce a memory leak if not unsubscribed.

But there is a big difference. In the duplicate, the Subject is a member of a long living service. In your case, the Subject is a member of the component.

@jabaa, You are right, that's the difference

I guess, you don't have to unsubscribe in your case, but I'm not sure.

@JSONDerulo Isn't this question different than the one marked as duplicate question. Like jabaa said In the original question Subject is a member of a long living service. Here, the Subject is a member of the component.

I think, it's still a duplicate. Read point 2 in the accepted answer. The problem could be a circular reference. That would mean that you still have to unsubscribe.

I have setup a simple StackBlitz to demonstrate that even Subscriptions to Observables created within the same component can leak: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gtebbr?file=src%2Fmain.ts Check the console. Even after the component is destroyed, the Observable keeps pushing new items.
